# Iptables Traffic forward

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, forwarding, helpdesk

Would you please help me .
I have a 2 vps (Ubuntu)
I want to forward all traffic from one vps(1.1.1.1) to another (2.2.2.2) vps
except ssh port on A vps(1.1.1.1)
A server is 1.1.1.1
B server is 2.2.2.2

1st try:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 1.1.1.1 -j DNAT --to 2.2.2.2
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -d 1.1.1.1 -p tcp  --dport 22 -j REJECT
iptables -A FORWARD  -i eth0 -d 2.2.2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

2nd try

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j DNAT --to-destination 1.1.1.1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.2
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT
```

Both failed

Comment: What have you tried? How it failed?

Comment: sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
 iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 1.1.1.1 -j DNAT --to 2.2.2.2
 iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -d 1.1.1.1 -p tcp  --dport 22 -j REJECT
 iptables -A FORWARD  -i eth0 -d 2.2.2 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

Comment: Please add additional information to the question by editing so that it is properly formatted.

Comment: sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j DNAT --to-destination 1.1.1.1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.2
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT